# Is there a way to change a value with a key press while other value raises?

Tags: c++, windows, loops

I want to make a function that changes 'y' value only on each 'spacebar' press while 'x' value raises meanwhile without any key presses. So far I made a program,which increases 'y' value and 'x' value on each 'spacebar' press...but thats not what I want... This is my program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int key=getch();
int x,y;

int main()
{
    for(int z=1;z<200;z++){
        for(x,y;x<100,y<100;){

            if(x<100){
                x++;
                system("cls");
                cout<<"x:"<<x<<endl;
                cout<<"y:"<<y<<endl;
                Sleep(100);
            }
            if(y<100){
                if(key == 32){
                    y+=5;
                    system("cls");
                    cout<<"x:"<<x<<endl;
                    cout<<"y:"<<y<<endl;
                    Sleep(100);
                    key=getch();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"loop ended"<<endl;
    Sleep(3000);
    return 0;
```

And I also want to stop the user from holding down the 'spacebar' and make value 'y' only press to increase kind of... Please help.

Comment: Detecting keyboard interaction natively is OS dependent. That's not supported by standard c++.

Comment: You will need to *research* the API for your operating system for "Key press" and "Key Release".  Some operating systems may not have this functionality (like in console mode when dealing with external terminals).

Answer (score 0):

In your code `getch` (even the one before `main`) waits for the key to be pressed. Try using the function `_kbhit()` from `<conio.h>` for checking whether a key has been pressed.  Look into MSDN's C Runtime Library Reference (somewhere within https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library) to learn about the API details. Note that `getch` (consider using the preferred name `_getch`) may require you to make 2 calls for some keys so that you can interpret the results correctly.

Note this is Windows specific (and C rather than C++).  As others noted there might not be a portable standard C or C++ way of achieving what you want; you may need to rely on a platform specific APIs like these.